# Multi Tenant Azure AD App with Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I am working on creating an Azure Function that is secured by an Azure AD App. I have the Azure Function part working and it is secured by Azure AD but now I would like to allow users in other tenants to be able to call this Azure Function and access the resources in their tenant

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change **Supported account types** to **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)**.

On the **Azure Active Directory Settings** blade, switch the value of the **Management mode** option to **Advanced**.

Next, clear the value in the **Issuer Url** field. This will allow users from other Azure Active Directories to authenticate against your API.

At last, consent the use of the API in your tenant.

See details steps from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi-multitenant#create-a-multi-tenant-enterprise-api-secured-with-azure-ad). (ignore the operations related to SharePoint)